# select 4 different tables to be columns in 1 row in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, multiple-columns

I'm a beginner at SQL Server and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to solve this problem:

EDIT

Tbl_Product

| ProdCode | Batchno |
| --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 |

Tbl_Production

| ProdCode | Batchno | FORNumber | FORQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 |

Tbl_Adjusment

| ProdCode | Batchno | ADNumber | ADQTYin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | AD/MLP/1022/0016 | 3000 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | AD/MLP/1022/0017 | 5948 |

Tbl_Assembly

| ProdCode | Batchno | TranNumber | TranQTYOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | AS/MLP/1022/0135 | 6038 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | AS/MLP/1022/0139 | 3000 |

`Code` and `Batch` make up the primary key.

My query is :

```
SELECT   
    Tbl_Product.ProdCode,
    Tbl_Product.Batchno,
    Tbl_Production.FORNumber,
    Tbl_Production.FORQTY,
    Tbl_Adjusment.ADNumber, 
    Tbl_Adjusment.ADQTYin,
    Tbl_Assembly .TranNumber, 
    Tbl_Assembly .TranQTYOut
FROM 
    Tbl_Product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Tbl_Production ON Tbl_Product.ProdCode = Tbl_Production.ProdCode 
                   AND Tbl_Product.Batchno = Tbl_Production.Batchno  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Tbl_Adjusment ON Tbl_Product.ProdCode = Tbl_Adjusment.ProdCode   
                  AND Tbl_Product.Batchno = Tbl_Adjusment.Batchno  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Tbl_Assembly ON Tbl_Product.ProdCode = Tbl_Assembly.ProdCode  
                 AND Tbl_Product.Batchno = Tbl_Assembly.Batchno 
WHERE
    Tbl_Product.ProdCode = 'KK1212LYR' 
    AND Tbl_Product.Batchno = '22206233'
```

and result (duplicate columns ADNumber, ADQTYin, TranNumber, TranQTYOut) :

| ProdCode | Batchno | FORNumber | FORQTY | ADNumber | ADQTYin | TranNumber | TranQTYOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0016 | 3000 | AS/MLP/1022/0135 | 6038 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0016 | 3000 | AS/MLP/1022/0139 | 3000 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0017 | 5948 | AS/MLP/1022/0135 | 6038 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0017 | 5948 | AS/MLP/1022/0139 | 3000 |

I want to get a result like this :

| ProdCode | Batchno | FORNumber | FORQTY | ADNumber | ADQTYin | TranNumber | TranQTYOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0016 | 3000 | AS/MLP/1022/0135 | 6038 |
| KK1212LYR | 22206233 | FOR/MLP/1022/0137 | 830 | AD/MLP/1022/0017 | 5948 | AS/MLP/1022/0139 | 3000 |

Is this possible?

Comment: I *assume* you are after `JOIN`s here, however, I don't see what relates `AD001` and `SL001`. Are we missing some columns in the relationship(s) here?

Comment: The logic how/why you want to get the outcome you've shown is unknown. So if you want to get help on this, you will need to explain it.

Comment: thank you all for the response, actually I want to make a report on the stock of incoming and outgoing goods from production, stock adjustments and sales transactions, and will be displayed on the Crystal Report

Comment: i tried with left outer join on Code and Batch, but data becomes duplicate rows with many rows generated

Comment: As said, you need to tell us the logic how to get the desired outcome. From the information and sample input you've shown, your result doesn't make sense. So you are either missing to tell us some important information or you just can't do what you want.

Comment: sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I edited my question with the actual data in my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the suggested results, because there is no relationship among ProdNo, AdNo, and SlNo.  What you can do is get, by product, the total of production, adjustments, and sales with the following:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Batch, ISNULL(pr.ProdQty,0) as ProdQty, ISNULL(ad.AdQty,0) as AdQty, ISNULL(sl.SlQty,0) as SlQty
FROM Tbl_Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Code, Batch, SUM(ProdQty) AS ProdQty FROM Tbl_Production GROUP BY Code, Batch) pr ON p.Batch = pr.Batch AND p.Code = pr.Code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Code, Batch, SUM(AdQty) AS AdQty FROM Tbl_Adjustment GROUP BY Code, Batch) ad ON p.Batch = ad.Batch AND p.Code = ad.Code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Code, Batch, SUM(SlQty) AS SlQty FROM Tbl_Sales GROUP BY Code, Batch) sl ON p.Batch = sl.Batch AND p.Code = sl.Code
```

Note that even though the sample data did not require it, left joins were used in case any product was missing any of production, adjustments, or sales.

If you really need production #1 associated with adjustment #1 associated with sales #1 then the *No columns should be turned into integers, dropping the first two characters (which are useless anyway).  If you do that, the following will get you those results:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Batch, n.Nbr, pr.ProdQty, ad.AdQty, sl.SlQty
FROM Tbl_Product p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ProdNo AS Nbr FROM Tbl_Production UNION SELECT AdNo FROM Tbl_Adjustment UNION SELECT SlNo FROM Tbl_Sales) n 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Production pr ON p.Code = pr.Code AND p.Batch = pr.Batch AND n.Nbr = pr.ProdNo
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Adjustment ad ON p.Code = ad.Code AND p.Batch = ad.Batch AND n.Nbr = ad.AdNo
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Sales sl ON p.Code = sl.Code AND p.Batch = sl.Batch AND n.Nbr = sl.SlNo
```

Comment: how about using a pivot table? by combining data in a table into 1 column then using pivot

Comment: It all depends on how ugly you want your database.  Different data should be kept in different tables.